# Perturbation method that could capture the global behavior?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

Today I encountered this regular perturbation problem (from a habit of doing random math problems on boring classes):

$$y''(x)=-\epsilon  y(x)^2-\sin (x),y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$$

A regular perturbation series using $y_0 + \epsilon y_1 + \epsilon^2 y_2$ gives:

$$
\sin (x) + \frac{1}{8} \epsilon  \left(-2 x^2-\cos (2 x)+1\right) + \epsilon ^2 \left(\frac{1}{72} \left(-9 \left(4 x^2-27\right) \sin (x)-96 x-\sin (3 x)\right)-2 x \cos (x)\right)
$$
Graphically (with $\epsilon = 0.1$, green-dashed is $sin(x)$, red-dashed is the perturbation solution, and blue-solid is the numerical solution) we have the figure below. The real solution (blue-solid) seems to develop a singularity around 12, as complained by Mathematica's NDSolve command, but I don't see that the regular perturbation solution would be able to capture it -- even with more terms as they are just combinations of polynomials and trigonometry functions.

[image: comparison of sine function, perturbation and numerical solutions]

So my question is if there are other, in some sense "more advanced" perturbation methods that could capture the global picture. I have Bender's book and will look into it, meanwhile I think it's a good idea to post it here as a question, as someone may point me a more precise direction.

Comment: What was $\epsilon$ for your plot?

Comment: @David I apologize for missing it, the value is 0.1, I will update the question.

Comment: Using Matlab I got the solution a bit past 12. I have a feeling your equation doesn't have a solution that persists for all $x$. If you rescale with $y=\epsilon^{-1}Y$ (this is the other balance along with the regular scaling you used), you get the equation $Y''+Y^2=0$ (valid for $y$ with large magnitude). This will diverge faster than any polynomial/exponential function, so getting any handle on the behaviour will be hard/impossible.

Comment: @David Hello David, this kind of qualitative analysis is exactly what I am looking for, the singularity occurs (in Mathematica) around 12.88. The simplified equation you gave doesn't seem to have an analytical solution, although it can be transformed into a 1st order equation as $y'=\sqrt{1-2/3 y^3}$. From which it is clear that $y$ will explode at certain point. I think the $sin(x)$ mitigate this explosion a little bit.